# How get data from API link

Tags: javascript, arrays

How I get data from API link

`https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/geo.js`

I use the code bellow but not working. Please anyone talk what I wrong here?

`

```
<div id="divIDClass"></div>
<script>
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/geo.js',
  success: function(data){
    document.getElementById('divIDClass').innerHTML = data.country_code);
  }
})
</script>
```

`

Show undefined inner html

Comment: 1. you have a syntax error (the closing `)` after `data.country_code`
2. the url you are requesting is supposed to be used differently, you probably want the JSON endpoint `https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/geo.json` which returns JSON and not a JavaScript file

Comment: Try to add a error callback supplied by jQuery. I see the url doesn't give proper json, but its having some wrapping "geoio(...)" around json. You may need to accept raw text response from URL and remove unnecessary data and parse it.

Answer (score 1):

The response is not a valid JSON structure. When checking the response from that endpoint, it returns a string in the format `geoip({ /* data here */ })`

If you check the website https://geojs.io, they show an example of how to use it. You need to create a function named `geoip()` that receives a JSON object. In that function, you will be able to handle the response. Then, you create a `<script>` tag and set the source to be that address you made a request to. When that script gets loaded, it calls your `geoip()` function.

Check the website to see how to use it.

If you still want to make requests yourself and want the country details in JSON format, you can use the endpoint `https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/country.json` (see the [doc](https://www.geojs.io/docs/v1/endpoints/country/))

Example:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/country.json',
  success: (data, status, req) => {
    // print the data in the console as it comes, to check on the structure
    console.log(data);
    
    // add it to the DOM
    $('#response').html(`Country: ${data.name} (${data.country}/${data.country_3}), ip: ${data.ip},`);
  },
  error: (req, errorMessage) => console.error(errorMessage)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="response"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it is not a json, you shuld use the example from docs https://www.geojs.io/:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    function geoip(json){
      var userip      = document.getElementById("user_ip");
      var countrycode = document.getElementById("user_countrycode");
      userip.textContent      = json.ip;
      countrycode.textContent = json.country_code;
    }
</script>
<script async src="https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/geo.js"></script>
```

If you still want to use ajax:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/geo.js',
      success: function(data){
data = JSON.parse(data.slice(6,-1));
        document.getElementById('divIDClass').innerHTML = data.country_code);
      }
    })
</script>
```